# Can Thunderbird send an out-of-office autoreply?

Tags: thunderbird, email

I couldn't find a way to configure out of office auto reply mechanism in Thunderbird like there is in Outlook. The only way i have found through searching online is to create a message filter but that needs the laptop and Thunderbird to be running all the time, which is stupid in my view. Please share if you know a way.

Comment: The question is interesting, but I do not agree with the *stupidity*, because if the client could be closed, so it is a mail server configuration, that is completely different.

Comment: But if you're on vacation then you wouldn't keep your laptop at home running. That's my concern

Answer (score 3):

Thunderbird and Outlook are local E-Mail-Clients so they must be running to answer your E-Mails. The difference is, that Outlook is often connected to an Exchange-Server which sends those Messages on your behalf (and runs all the time btw.). Thunderbird doesn't have such a Server equivalent and therefore doesn't provide the functionality you are asking for. You need to find out which Mailserver your company is running and configure your out-of-office note there (ask an Admin).

Comment: btw any extention which might be able to communicate with the exchange server the way Outlook does?

Comment: @subeh.sharma I doubt this exists, see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=477418

Answer (score 0):

Probably we can work with the add-on for Lightning being worked upon which definitely solves the extended out-of-office functionality but lacks in caching of events.
How you do it is..
1. Install the add-on from https://www.1st-setup.nl/wordpress/?page_id=133

1. Map it using the EWS setting as mentioned in the FAQ.
2. Whether use the calendaring or not it do a **RIGHT_CLICK on the Calendar -> Click 
   Out_Of_Office_settings**
3. That is all you need.